# Visual Studio 2015 git commit folder structure

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-2015, gitlab

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2015 as my main dev tool and with git functionality I keep running to problems with folder structure.

Example:
VS2015 Python Project.

```
Solution(sprinter)
-Project(sprinter)
--Project Environments
--Folder(sprinter, holds the main files)
--requirements.txt
--runserver.py
```

When I go to commit this to an empty git repo, on say GitLab, instead of it committing the files in "Folder(sprinter) and the requirements file (which I have to only include, everything else is excluded). I get this.

```
Repo(sprinter) 
- sprinter
--sprinter
---sprinter(folder with files)
---requirements.txt
```

I've not seen anyone else on github or gitlab with this structure, it's usually just the source files:

```
-static
-content
-requirements.txt
-app.py
```

Am I doing something wrong with how I do the initial push?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong with how I do the initial push?

Not with the initial push, no.

But the way the git repo has been initialized can explain why: it has been created above the `sprinter` solution folder, instead of *inside* it.

Check if you reproduce the issue with [this Git-Visual Studio tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-vs)).

Comment: I seem to able to resolve it if I create from an existing folder with content in it. But when I do a fresh New>Project>Python>Flask Website and Add to source control, it does the same thing and sticks the .git in the project director not in the sprinter folder like you suggested.